# rails paperclip default image with S3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3, storage, paperclip

I'm trying to use the default_url in my application but I store the images using S3. I'm not sure what URL I need to put in there or if I have to create a fake image just to get everything up there.

Since my images always render through S3, I don't know if it would work if I just put in some default images in my public folder. It doesn't seem to be working now - I also only have one image in there, and I know it has to resize. I can manually put the resized images in there but I'm still not sure what URL to use with default. Please help :)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I use paperclip with S3 with default images in the public folder. It works fine. My default_url statement looks like this:

```
:default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png'
```

which means that for my attachment named avatar, setup with the styles small and large, I must create and put these images in the public dir:

- /images/avatar/missing_small.png
- /images/avatar/missing_large.png

It's [pretty well documented](http://rubydoc.info/gems/paperclip/Paperclip/ClassMethods#has_attached_file-instance_method).

For your reference, or in the case the problem is really somewhere else, here is my full paperclip statement:

```
has_attached_file :avatar,
  :styles => { :small => '60x60#', :large => '300x300#' }, :default_style => :large,
  :storage => :s3,
  :default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png',
  :path => "users/:id/avatar/:style.:extension",
  :bucket => "bucket name",
  :s3_credentials => {
    :access_key_id => "access key id",
    :secret_access_key => "secret access key"
  },
  :url => ":s3_alias_url", # These two are only required when you alias S3 - e.g. want to use cdn.example.com rather than s3.amazonaws.com
  :s3_host_alias => "my.aws.alias"
```

Comment: did not work for me. all my attachments served from S3, but default_url through assets pipeline for some reason.

Comment: I didn't need the full path. Apparently the default_url just looks in the images folder.

Comment: Your server should serve static assets as well...otherwise, it is not going to work

Comment: well this solution does not work if you are deploying on heroku since they does not allow images to be stored in the public folder

Comment: @SsouLlesS, my solution for heroku is to manually specify the path to S3. Here is what mine looks like:
`:default_url => "https://s3.amazonaws.com/images.myapp/default/:style/default_image.jpg"`

I then manually uploaded the file to Amazon S3 in 3 different styles, in their accompanying folders.

Answer (score 4):

try this out: 
`:default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('missing.png')`

Comment: This is the correct solution because if you need to modify your default image, it will automatically bust the cache of the browser and download the new, updated image.