# How and where paperclip via aws-sdk store URLs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, paperclip

Sorry for maybe dumb question, but I have some misunderstanding about how Paperclip works. If I use it with aws-sdk gem, where image urls are stored?

My model has only fields like `image_name`, `image_size`, but not something like `image_url`. I also tried to list all tables from my db in sql console, but there wasn't any special image-related tables. I know what I can access url by calling `my_model.image.url`, but I need understanding, where this url is located. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The urls are auto generated based on the ruleset you have in your paperclip config file. They usually include the name and id of your model unless you have changed the defaults. Set the `:default_url` option when you call `has_attached_file` if you want to change it:

```
:default_url => '/images/:attachment/missing_:style.png',
:path => "avatars/:id/:style/:filename"
```

More background: [rails paperclip default image with S3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1781128/rails-paperclip-default-image-with-s3)

Comment: I also found [this](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/attachment.rb#L139), so now I'm sure about auto-generating. Thanks!